# Set HTML5 <video> as background to a specified height of div

Tags: html, css

I want to show HTML5 video with content over it. Like a background image. The whole div/HTML5 video must be a 400px height. I don't want to use the video as a full page background, but on a specified height.

```
    <div style="height: 400px">
     <video controls poster="{{item.media_pic}}">
    <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-4>
      some text
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-8>
    button         
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
<div style="height: 400px;position:relative;background:#000">
     <video controls poster="{{item.media_pic}}" style="position:absolute;height:100%;">
    <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://www.papytane.com/mp4/accrobra.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
  <ion-row style="position:relative;z-index:9">
    <ion-col col-4>
      some text
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-8>
    button         
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</div>
```

Add "position:absolute" to the video tag and add 100% height to fit it's parent div's height.

Add "position:relative" to the parent div of the video tag to hold the video inside as we have applied position absolute to it.

Comment: Thats great man. what i wanted but it doesn't play the video. I added controls. i mean i dont want autoplay i want button to play

Comment: Glad it helped, and just now I have modified my code to match your requirement. :)

Comment: For future reference thats the answer for everybody with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="image_box">
    <video controls poster="{{item.media_pic}}">
        <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="{{item.image_path}}" type="video/ogg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-4>some text</ion-col>
        <ion-col col-8>button</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.image_box{
    width:100% !important;;
    height:400px !important;;
}
```

Comment: i tried that Alchemist. It wouldn't work for me, it doesnt make it a background, i mean the <video> tag

Comment: @SimonIoa if it does not make it a background, what it does then?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`object-fit: cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) , [position absolute,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on the child then [position relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on the parent may help you achieve the desired effect.

do not forget to add [overflow: hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) on the parent element:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
figure{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red; 
  overflow: hidden
}
video{
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 28vh;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <video controls >
 

      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
              type="video/mp4">

      Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
  </video>
  <figcaption>My Nice video</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: click on Full page to see it in action